# Navigation Bar default view

Tags: ios

In my app I have a `tableViewController` where I have added a `UINavigationController` and a `BackButton` programmatically:

```
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:navController.view];
    self.title =@"A";
    UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backPressed:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btw;
```

But the output is not the same as the default navigation bar and as the default back button.

This is what I mean with default navigation bar and default back button:

[image]

And this is how it looks with my custom code:

[image]

How could I get the same output with code?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why don't you set up the controller hierarchy with your controller embedded in a navigation controller in the first place? Creating a navigation controller with self as the root view controller, then adding the navigation controller's view as a subview is a strange (and wrong) thing to do.

Comment: @rdelmar, ,you are right, but I don't get it work as it should. I need to pass a value to the second view controller and I don't know how to do it using the storyboard.

Comment: @rdelmar, already solved using embedded navigation controller and prepareforsegue method...thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set up navigationBar frame with following code:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar = CGRectMake(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.x, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width, 64);
```

and use this method:

```
-(UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar
{
    return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
}
```

Don't forget to set up delegate of navigation bar

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Thank you, I a getting some errors. The compiler proposes to change the property navigationBar with navigationItem, and if changed, then  says that the property frame is not found on object UINavigationItem.